# Feature "my tags" tab in "main" site view too

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

It would be nice to have the `my tags` tab straight in the "main" page, I find myself often scrolling up and down hunting highlighted questions in the main page. `interesting` is close, but it shows too much for what I'd like.

Here is the "main" page (stackoverflow.com).

[image: Main]

Here is the "unanswered" (stackoverflow.com/unanswered) which features the aforementioned `my tags` tab

[image: Unanswered]

Comment: On the [meta-tag:new-nav], this feature exists as a tag option dropdown on the left side of the navigation.  See this [screenshot for the new nav](http://imgur.com/BBcqLPV)

Comment: Also, you can just do a search for `intags:mine`

Comment: @ryanyuyu I wasn't aware of that upcoming change, I'll opt-in and see how it works

Comment: @Alex yeah it's not bad.  There are still a few bugs (I noticed that [tag searching is kinda broken](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259915/hard-to-exclude-tags-in-search-for-new-nav))  I guess you can always revert and opt-out later if you don't like it.